# CIFS mount error(2): No such file or directory

Tags: networking, mount, samba, cifs

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 desktop on a new computer yesterday, and today I am trying to connect to a Windows 10 share on my internal network (LAN) with CIFS.    The Windows 10 machine has two drives, and it shares its D: drive as "D Share" with a space.  Other Windows computers on this network regularly attach to this share, so I know it's active.  I also verified that the machine is at 192.168.0.2.

I have tried many configurations of the share name, but all attempts return "mount error(2): No such file or directory" and dmesg returns:

```
CIFS:   VFS: BAD NETWORK NAME: \\192.168.0.2\D:
CIFS:   VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

I have tried these:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=James96,password=abcde //192.168.0.2/D: /mnt/smb_share
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=James96,password=abcde //192.168.0.2/D/ /mnt/smb_share
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=James96,password=abcde //192.168.0.2/D Share /mnt/smb_share (this one returns "bad usage" so it doesn't like the space).  
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=James96,password=abcde //192.168.0.2/$D Share /mnt/smb_share
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=James96,password=abcde //192.168.0.2/D_Share /mnt/smb_share
```

So my question is:  how do I specify the share name where it's shared as D Share in Windows?

Other info:

```
$ uname -r 
5.13.0-30 generic
```

```
$ mount.cifs -V
version 6.9
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the `/mnt/smb_share` directory exist, before the `mount`?

Comment: Yes that folder exists.  I created it yesterday.

Comment: I can't see that you tried to escape space or use quotation mark. So this should work: `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=James96,password=abcde "//192.168.0.2/D Share" /mnt/smb_share` and `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=James96,password=abcde //192.168.0.2/D\ Share /mnt/smb_share`

Comment: Thanks for that comment.  I will try it in quotes.  I just solved the problem another way -- I created a share on  folder on that drive, and the share name has no spaces in it.  That worked.  So the problem was the space and your answer should help.

Comment: @Mateusz -- yes, you're right.  When I put it in quotes as you showed it works.  Thanks.